# scikit-sparseがpip installできない

Tags: python, pip

pythonのバージョンは3.9.5です。
scikit-sparseをインストールしたいのですがエラーばかりで全く分かりません。これまでの経緯は以下です。まず

```
py -m pip install scikit-sparse
```

をしたところエラーがでました。powershellをとじてしまったので正確な内容は覚えていませんがvisual studio build toolsをインストールしろというものでした。C/C++でくんだことがないので詳しくわかりませんがC/C++のコンパイラが必要な感じでした。
そのためエラー内容にかいてあったURLにとびvisual studio build toolsをインストールした後、再度scikit-sparseをインストールしました。なおこのときsetuptoolsとpip自体は更新済です。すると次のエラーがでました。

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\･･･\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\･･･\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\･･･\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpciy8jl30'
（中略）
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-sparse
Failed to build scikit-sparse
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-sparse, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

内容的にcl.exeが見つからないとのことだったので私はパスが通ってないのだと思いました。そこでエクスプローラに

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64
```

を打ち込んで検索をかけたところcl.exeの存在を確認したので環境変数の編集から

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64
```

を新規追加してもう一度pip installしました。が、cl.exeが見つからないという同様のエラーがでて現在に至ります。
もうお手上げ状態でさっぱりわかりません。どなたか助けていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 本当のエラーは`(中略)`された部分にあって、`'cholmod.h'というファイルが無い`というものでしょう。検索したらこんなリポジトリ [xmlyqing00/Cholmod-Scikit-Sparse-Windows](https://github.com/xmlyqing00/Cholmod-Scikit-Sparse-Windows) が見つかったので、何か出来るかもしれません。調べてみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはそこでも参照している [jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows](https://github.com/jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows) で何とかしたらしい [install scikit-sparse on win7(halfway)](https://graziegrazie.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/05/24/114155) を参考にしてみるとか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。まさにその通りでcholmod.hというファイルが無いと書いてありました。そちらのリンク先で解決できないか試してみます。