# scikit-sparseインストール時のエラーを解決できない

Tags: python

タイトルの通り、[scikit-sparse パッケージ](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse) をインストールしたいのですが、エラーを解決できず行き詰っております。
Pythonのバージョンはpython 3.10.7です。

PowerShell から以下の通りコマンドを一行ずつ順に試してみましたが、エラーが発生してしまいます。
(エラーメッセージ中の "hogehoge" はユーザー名です)

英語はわかりませんが、pipの問題ではないと言っていることはわかりました。
また、setup.pyがどうも実行できていないということも何となくわかりました。
しかし、ではどう解決したらいいのかということがわかりません。
ご助言をいただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
py -m pip install -U pip
py -m pip install -U wheel
py -m pip install -U setuptools
py -m pip install scikit-sparse
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Collecting scikit-sparse
  Using cached scikit-sparse-0.4.4.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\hogehoge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-sparse) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\hogehoge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-sparse) (1.7.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-sparse
  Building wheel for scikit-sparse (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\test_cholmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse/_version.py to '0.4.4'
      running build_ext
      skipping 'sksparse\cholmod.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'sksparse.cholmod' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\sksparse
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310/include -I/usr/include/suitesparse -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsksparse\cholmod.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\sksparse\cholmod.obj
      cholmod.c
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iu1qbymb\scikit-sparse_3040893b73c5464a8fdd40f0232c94fe\sksparse\cholmod_backward_compatible.h(1): fatal error C1083: include ファイルを開けません。'cholmod.h':No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-sparse
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-sparse
Failed to build scikit-sparse
Installing collected packages: scikit-sparse
  Running setup.py install for scikit-sparse ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for scikit-sparse did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\test_cholmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      copying sksparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      copying sksparse\test_data\well1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse\test_data
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sksparse/_version.py to '0.4.4'
      running build_ext
      skipping 'sksparse\cholmod.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'sksparse.cholmod' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\sksparse
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310/include -I/usr/include/suitesparse -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsksparse\cholmod.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\sksparse\cholmod.obj
      cholmod.c
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      C:\Users\hogehoge\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iu1qbymb\scikit-sparse_3040893b73c5464a8fdd40f0232c94fe\sksparse\cholmod_backward_compatible.h(1): fatal error C1083: include ファイルを開けません。'cholmod.h':No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> scikit-sparse

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: 解決した記事では無いですが、こちらと同件かもしれません。[scikit-sparseがpip installできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/85849/26370)

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse#with-pip suite-sparse というライブラリに依存していると書いてあります。 https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html Windowsで動くようには見えませんが、これを自分でビルドしたわけでは（おそらくは）ないですよね

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。また、返信遅れてすみません。リンク先を確認したのですが、結論から言うと上手くできませんでした（kunifさん）。英語が苦手ですべて読めていないのですが、scikit-sparseは、windowsでは動かないのでしょうか（suite-sparseに依存し、かつそのライブラリがwindowsでは動かないため）？なお、こちらの使用PCはwindowsです（quickquipさん）。

Comment: 検索して見つかるこの辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[SuiteSparse，Metis のインストール（ソースコードを使用）（Windows 上）](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/suitesparse.html), [Windows環境下のcmake 3.17でIntel MKLのBLAS/LAPACKを使ってSuiteSparseをbuildするメモ](https://qiita.com/mocobt/items/96ba2c8f3be673142854), [suitesparse-windows-binaries/SUITESPARSEREADME.md](https://github.com/Phylliida/suitesparse-windows-binaries/blob/master/SUITESPARSEREADME.md), [Phylliida/suitesparse-windows-binaries](https://github.com/Phylliida/suitesparse-windows-binaries)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試す価値がある記事でした。また、時間のある時にチャレンジしてみます。